# JRadioButton cannot be cast to JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jradiobutton

I have `actionPerformed()` method which does two things: print out the radio buttons selected and set visibility of labels in another class. I get *cannot be cast to* error when the radio button is clicked.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("Selected: " + e.getActionCommand());
    JButton hiddenBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if (hiddenBtn == submit)
    {
        Class o = new Class();
        o.foo();
    }
    JButton close = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if (close == purchase)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I get the error at `(JButton) e.getSource()`.

Answer (score 4):

[`JRadioButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) does not extend `JButton`. Therefore, you cannot cast it to a `JButton`. You can, however, cast to an `AbstractButton`.

```
java.lang.Object
  java.awt.Component
      java.awt.Container
          javax.swing.JComponent
              javax.swing.AbstractButton
                  javax.swing.JToggleButton
                      javax.swing.JRadioButton
```

Answer (score 2):

Their least upper bound of JButton and JRadioButton is [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html). You can cast to that, i think, to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the technical aspect of whether or not casting works, think logically on the reason behind casting a JRadioButton with a JButton. The usage of both are different.

Answer (score 0):

In connection with `AbstractButton` or `JButton` use [ButtonGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html), because if you add `JRadioButton(s)` to the `ButtonGroup`, then only one `JRadioButton` could be selected,

I can simulating this error about cannot be cast to `javax.swing.AbstractButton` or cannot be cast to `javax.swing.JButton` from un-correct usage renderer in the `JTable`

Comment: > 95 % unrelated to the question